# Giving every ocurrence in a table a count based in order on SQL

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have table in a SQL like database schema called Snowflake similar to PostgreSQL, which contains the following rows:

```
server_time, user_id, transaction_id, revenue_eur
```

I am trying to see the re-conversion, so I want to count for each user what was his first, second, third... purchased. Snowflakes allows LATERAL JOINS but I am not sure how to do it.

The output should look like:

```
      date     user_id   purchased_number
   2019-07-25  123121         1
   2019-07-26  123121         2
   2019-07-27  123121         3
   2019-07-25   8565          1  
   2019-07-25   8565          2
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is typically done using window functions:

```
select cast(server_time as date), user_id, 
       row_number() over (partition by user_id order by server_time) as purchased_number
from the_table;
```

Assuming `server_time` is a column defined with the `timestamp` data type, the expression `cast(server_time as date)` would convert that into a "plain" date (without a time). The above is ANSI standard SQL, but I don't know if Snowflake supports that. If not, you need to consult the manual on how to cast a `timestamp` value to a `date` value.

Comment: thank you am pretty new to SQL and this worked perfectly. Cast works with snowflake, I was usint ´TO_DATE´ which is similar, I guess. Will have to look the documentaton.

Comment: @JorgeRodriguezMolinuevo: `to_date()` converts a string to a date. It should not be used to change a `timestamp` value to a different data type. You should look for a function named `to_char()` that _formats_ a timestamp (or date) value to something different